# $a,b,c > 0$ such that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=\sqrt[3]{ab+bc+ca} $ prove that $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc \le \frac{4}{27}$

Tags: inequality

I have a series of problems in inequalities that I can not solve,please help me if you can.

problem 1 :$a,b,c \geq 0$ such that $\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}=\sqrt[3]{ab+bc+ca} $
prove that  $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc \le \frac{4}{27}$

problem 2 : $a,b,c\geq0$ and $a+b+c = 1$ prove that

1, $ \sqrt{a+\frac{(b-c)^2}{4}}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c} \leq \sqrt{3} $

2,  $\sqrt{a+\frac{(b-c)^2}{4}} +   \sqrt{b+\frac{(a-c)^2}{4}}  + \sqrt{c+\frac{(a-b)^2}{4}} \leq2$

problem 3 $a,b,c \geq0$ and $a+b+c=1$ find Maximum value of : 
$M=\frac{1+a^2}{1+b^2}+\frac{1+b^2}{1+c^2}+\frac{1+c^2}{1+a^2}$

Comment: Problem 3 is not a problem... I think there is a typo...

Comment: yeah,i've fixed it already :D,sorry for that

Comment: Do you have some insights or references you are willing to share with us?

Comment: actually this is my younger brother's problem,I saw him strugling with these problem for over a week and I just wanna help him a bit,though I'm not very good at Math.

Comment: It would be better to post these as four separate problems, including any thoughts you or your brother have and what concepts he is familiar with.

Comment: @Aerrozard There seems to be a typo with Problem 3. Do you mean $ \frac {1+a^2}{1+b^2} + \frac {1+b^2}{1+c^2} + \frac {1+c^2}{1 + a^2} $?

Comment: feel free to use all of your knowledge,i'm able to explain to him what he couldn't understand.

Comment: @Aerrozard You should take Macavity's suggsestion.

Comment: Check your problem 2 also. The LHS of 2.1 is never greater than the LHS of 2.2, so equality cannot be there for 2.1 if 2.2 is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I will do #1 (the title problem) here:  The constraint gives -$$(a^2+b^2+c^2)^3 = (ab+bc+ca)^2$$

$$\therefore 3(a^2+b^2+c^2) \ge (a+b+c)^2  = (a^2+b^2+c^2)+2(a^2+b^2+c^2)^{3/2} $$

$$\implies a^2+b^2+c^2 \le 1 \implies a+b+c \le \sqrt3$$

Now the result follows from $a^2b+b^2c+c^2a+abc \le \frac4{27}(a+b+c)^3 \le \frac{4\sqrt3}{9} ...(1)$, with equality when $a = b = c = \frac1{\sqrt 3}$.

Proof of $(1)$ - let $b$ be the median of $a, b, c$.  Then $(b-c)(b-a) \le 0 \implies b^2+ac \le b(a+c)$. So we have
$$a^2b+c(b^2+ac)+abc \le b(a+c)^2  \le \frac4{27} (a+b+c)^3$$

Note that this means your #1 question was incorrect, the maximum of LHS is $3\sqrt3$ times the RHS in that inequality.

Answer (score 1):

*Sketch to #3*

We can use the method of [Lagrange Multipliers]. Let $ f(a,b,c) = a + b + c $. This is our restraint function, where the restraint is $ f(a,b,c) = 1 $. Let $$ g(a,b,c) = \dfrac {1 + a^2}{1 + b^2} + \frac {1 + b^2}{1 + c^2} + \frac {1+c^2}{1 + a^2}. $$Then, we get $$ \nabla f = \left< 1, 1, 1 \right> $$ and $$ \nabla g = \left< \frac {2a \cdot \left( a^4 + 2a^2 - b^2c^2 - b^2 - c^2 \right)}{\left( a^2 + 1 \right)^2 \cdot \left( b^2 + 1 \right)}, - \frac {2b \cdot \left( a^2 + c^2 + a^2 - b^4 - 2b^2 + c^2 \right)}{\left( b^2 + 1 \right)^2 \cdot \left( c^2 + 1 \right)}, - \dfrac {2c \cdot \left( a^2 b^2 + a^2 + b^2 - c^4 - 2c^2 \right)}{\left( c^2 + 1 \right)^2 \cdot \left( a^2 + 1 \right)} \right>. $$Setting $ \nabla f \propto \nabla g $ gives us $$ \frac {2a \cdot \left( a^4 + 2a^2 - b^2c^2 - b^2 - c^2 \right)}{\left( a^2 + 1 \right)^2 \cdot \left( b^2 + 1 \right)} = - \frac {2b \cdot \left( a^2 + c^2 + a^2 - b^4 - 2b^2 + c^2 \right)}{\left( b^2 + 1 \right)^2 \cdot \left( c^2 + 1 \right)} = - \dfrac {2c \cdot \left( a^2 b^2 + a^2 + b^2 - c^4 - 2c^2 \right)}{\left( c^2 + 1 \right)^2 \cdot \left( a^2 + 1 \right)}. $$

Now we can solve and plug back into $ a + b + c = 1 $ and finish.

Comment: "Now we can solve"? I’m not sure at all that it leads to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$\frac{\sqrt b+\sqrt c}{\sqrt 2}=\sqrt{b+c-\frac{(\sqrt b-\sqrt c)^2}{2}}\le \sqrt{b+c-\frac{( b- c)^2}{4}}$$
 therefore from this and  Cauchy-Schwarz it follows that
$$\left( \sqrt{a+\frac{(b-c)^2}{4}}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}\right)^2\le \left(a+\frac{(b-c)^2}{4}+\frac{(\sqrt b+\sqrt c)^2}{ 2}\right)(1+2)\le 3\left(a+\frac{(b-c)^2}{4}+b+c -\frac{(b-c)^2}{4}\right)=3 $$